# Substance Painter hegiht map texture is missing details in Blender (Low poly)

Tags: uv, shaders

I made this texture in substance painter with some little details in the handle and handle protection:

[image]

But after exporting the textures and importing them in blender most of the details are missing:

[image]

You have to look very closely to see them, I set-up a principled bsdf with all the textures connected correctly and cycles as render engine.

Could this be because my model is very low poly? Or I am missing something?

[image]

Comment: One thing that you could try is experimental features and adaptative subdivision. https://youtu.be/hH8hoLuWyVU?t=125

Comment: Got it working with adaptative subdivision in simple mode. I noticed my mesh is too low poly also. Thank you!